# Do Lerna and Webpack do the same job?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, modularity, lerna

I'm quite confused about what learn does. Is it something like Webpack's code splitting? Should I have one Webpack configuration for each learn module or shouln't I use them together?

I'm trying to create modular react app. Any other resource would be great too!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`lerna` - A tool for managing JavaScript projects with multiple packages. To solve these (and many other) problems, some projects will organize their codebases into multi-package repositories (sometimes called monorepos)

see https://github.com/lerna/lerna

`webpack` - Packs many modules into a few bundled assets. Code Splitting allows to load parts for the application on demand.

There are diferrent. And what dose `create modular react app` mean? modular develop (es6/commonjs/amd) or dynamic modular loading?

Comment: Dynamic module loading. Should I use them together (I use JSX transpile, relay-compiler etc)

Comment: Just webpack, and if you new to react, try to use `create-react-app` setup your project

Comment: How do you manage chunked file (e.g 0.chunk.js) thats is manage from another package?